# Get p:selectOneRadio value to a JS function

Tags: primefaces, radio-button, submitchanges

I have a PF's selectOneRadio to choose a file type to download. Also I have a commandButton to call a download servlet using onclick attribute. The problem is that when I choose file type and click the button, the chosen value is of course not yet submitted. I'm looking for some way to get the chosen value available when I click on a download button.

Here's my code:

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="sorType" value="#{bean.type}" layout="custom">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="XML" itemValue="XML" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="XLS" itemValue="XLS" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="CSV" itemValue="CSV" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:commandButton type="button" ajax="false" onclick="return downloadFile('#{bean.type}');" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the selected value on client side, you will need to define `widgetVar` attribute for your `p:selectOneRadio`, for example:

```
<p:selectOneRadio widgetVar="widgetSorType" id="sorType" value="#{bean.type}"
    layout="custom">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="XML" itemValue="XML" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="XLS" itemValue="XLS" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="CSV" itemValue="CSV" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

This will allow the element to be easily found - you can then use it further to check which value was actually selected. I can see two options how to do it:

```
function getSelectedTypeVer1() {
    return PF('widgetSorType').getJQ().find(':checked').val() || "";
}

function getSelectedTypeVer2() {
    var inputs = PF('widgetSorType').inputs;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
            return inputs[i].value;
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Select whichever approach suits you better - both will return either the selected value or an empty string in case nothing has been selected. So all that remains is calling it in you button's `onclick` , so for example:

```
<p:commandButton type="button" ajax="false"
    onclick="return downloadFile(getSelectedTypeVer1());" />
```

Tested on PrimeFaces 5.2

Answer (score 3):

The solution shared by @Sva.Mu did not work for me.

I have an implementation quite similar to the last showcase in [PrimeFaces Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml) referred to custom layouts with some `<p:radioButton>` pointing their own `<f:selectItem>`.

Instead of use `PF('widgetName').getJQ().find(':checked').val();` I succeed with `PF('widgetName').inputs.filter(':checked').val();` merging in some way both approaches.

My version of PrimeFaces: 6.1